# Why is my logrotation not running properly in linux?

Tags: logrotate, amazon-linux

Can someone please help in identifying where I am going wrong. The log rotation I have setup for logs in a specific folder do not seem to be functioning properly.

**Below is my config:**

{

size 10M

rotate 3

compress

delaycompress

missingok

notifempty

create 0600 root root

}

The outcome of this is empty files and file names with multiple dates appended. **SCREENSHOT ATTACHED**. CONFUSED.

[image]

Comment: Hey can someone help here.

Comment: Post the FULL contents of both your `logrotate.conf` and the `logrotate.d` file in question. What you've posted so far is not a full example as it's missing what log path(s) you're rotating. See https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate if you need an example on how to make a properly formatted definition for `logrotate.d`.